# How to use php variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I realise that you can't use php in script, but I'm struggling to populate a chart with SQL data. Here is a simplified version of the code. I've read through the other exact questions on here but simply cannot get this to work.. hope someone can help, thanks

```
<?php
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT count(green), count(amber), count(red) FROM cards");
    $myData = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    $green = $myData['count(green)'];
    $amber = $myData['count(amber)'];
    $red = $myData['count(red)'];
?>  
<div id="students" style="height: 250px;">
<script type="text/javascript">
    Morris.Donut({
      element: 'students',
      data: [
        {value: '<?php $green; ?>', label: 'Green'},
        {value: '<?php $amber; ?>', label: 'Amber'},
        {value: '<?php $red; ?>', label: 'Red'},
      ],
      formatter: function (x) { return x }
    }).on('click', function(i, row){
      console.log(i, row);
    });
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: `<?php echo $green; ?>` or `<?=$green; ?>` and probably quotes around them.

Comment: nope this doesn't work

Comment: Define _doesn't work_?  What is the view source of the page?

Comment: My script code does not take values assigned in the php variables $green, $amber, $red.

Comment: You are missing the echo.... so instead `<?php $green; ?>` do `<?php echo $green; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

1. It is recommended to use mysql aliases to return readable keys:

```java
$query = mysql_query("SELECT count(green) as `cgreen`, count(amber) as `camber`, count(red) as `cred` FROM cards");
```

2. It is recommended to escape column-, table- and db-names:

```java
$query = mysql_query("SELECT count(`green`) as `cgreen`, count(`amber`) as `camber`, count(`red`) as `cred` FROM `cards`");
```

3. If you are using utf-8 as file-encoding it is quite easy to create a JSON in php and pass it to JS:

```java
$json = json_encode($myData);
```

```js
var tmpd = JSON.parse('<?=$json; ?>');
Morris.Donut({
  element: 'students',
  data: [
    {value: tmpd.cgreen, label: 'Green'},
    {value: tmpd.camber, label: 'Amber'},
    {value: tmpd.cred, label: 'Red'},
  ],
  formatter: function (x) { return x }
}).on('click', function(i, row){
  console.log(i, row);
});
```